# Macbook Air - with Ubuntu 14.04 how can i take print screen, page up/down cause there is no keyboard button

Tags: keyboard, 14.04, shortcut-keys, mouse, macbook

MacBook Air - Running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit Linux s 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

A) How to fix the keyboard keys which are not available in the built in Macbook Air keyboard?

```
1.  home key
2.  end key
3.  screen lock key
4.  pause or break key
5.  ins key
6.  del key


7.  page up (seems to be working by pressing FN + up )
8.  page down (seems to be working by pressing FN + down )
```

B) Mouse pad is not accurate while dragging it clicks without even i clicked on it, using external USB mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard):

Characters that are not printed on the keycaps (~,{},[],...) can still be generated as on a standard PC keyboard. Even if the @ is printed on another keycap as on the standard PC layout, that key will only behave like the standard PC layout key and not generate the @. Use your localized standard PC layout key (combination) to generate the @.

```
'fn'+'F-Key' -> triggers the regular F-Key    
'fn'+'Enter' -> Insert    
'fn'+'Backspace' -> Delete    
'fn'+'Up' -> PageUp    
'fn'+'Down' -> PageDown
'fn'+'Left' -> Home    
'fn'+'Right' -> End
'Clear' behaves like 'NumLock' (Numlock may also be 
   switched by pressing fn-F6 twice)
```

That link also provides methods on remapping keys.

Comment: Excellent thanks. How can i take "Print screen", i am still unable to take it via KEYBOARD cause there is no Print screen keyboard button.

Comment: Easiest is: Keyboard Shortcuts  and put a command to "Take Screenshot of a Window" and "Take Screenshot"

Comment: OK - GReat thank you. Normally in Mac OSX 10.9.2 > Taking screenshot requires to press > SHIFT + CMD + 3 = everything, 4 = region or so. BUT with UBUNTU seems not same.